# Is Google consider mobile phone specifications as copied content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, copyright, google-panda-algorithm

I have created a mobile niche blog a few weeks ago.

I am going to add a section to display mobile phone specifications.

Are those pages consider as copied content?

Example post......

**Samsung Galaxy S4 Review**

--Unique discription about phone ( 30-100 words)

- 2G Network   :GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900
- 3G Network   :HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100 4G
- Network  :LTE (market dependent)
- Type :Super AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
- Size :1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density)
- Multitouch :Yes
- Protection   :Corning Gorilla Glass 3
- MEMORY   Card slot   :microSD, up to 64 GB Internal  :16/32/64 GB storage,
  2 GB RAM
- Camera   :13 MP, 4128 x 3096 pixels, autofocus, LED flash, check
  quality
- OS   :Android OS, v4.2.2 (Jelly Bean)
- Chipset  :Exynos 5 Octa 5410
- CPU  Quad-core :1.6 GHz Cortex-A15 & quad-core 1.2 GHz Cortex-A7

--Describe about advantages and disadvantages(100-200 words)

-- A video review founded from YouTube

Is Google consider this type of page as copied content because of mobile phone specifications? (Those are appear in popular sites like gsmarena.com.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key here is not your specifications content but your "Describe about advantages and disadvantages" section. Make sure that its unique and is a little closer to 300+ words and you should be in a good shape. I would also put your descriptions above the specifications.

You mention other popular sites do the same thing but what they also do is wrap each review in other directly related content, links to similar items and etc. These items will help with relevancy and your CTR.

Comment: Thanks @dasickle . I will follow your suggestions. I will not mention all specification. So I am going to add a link called "check all specifications" to a gsmarena.com/specific-phone. Is it help to prevent copied issue also?

Comment: @Sasa1234 You can mention all specifications because its not going to effect your SEO in a negative way. The key is to add a good amount of original content around it. You want to just do a link then you can but I would what I originally suggested.